# $\psi:R \rightarrow S$, ring homomorphism. If $J$ is an ideal in $S$, prove that $\psi^{-1} (J)$ is an ideal in $R$ containing $\ker(\psi)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\psi : R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism, where $R$ and $S$ are commutative rings, and let $\ker (\psi) =I$. If $J$ is an ideal in $S$, prove that $\psi^{-1} (J)$ is an ideal in $R$ containing $I$.

What i know is $\psi(I)$ is an ideal of $\psi(S)$, since $\ker(\psi)=I$ states $I$ is an ideal of $R$. But having trouble with construction of $\psi^{-1}(J)$, is there any idea or prove for this statement?

Comment: We have $\phi^{-1}(\{0\}) = \ker\psi$. and so $\ker\psi\subseteq \psi^{-1}(J)$. What is $\psi(S)$?

Comment: How do we know that $\psi^{-1}$ exist ? or is it just a notation to show the inverse image of $\psi$ ?

Comment: A quick way to prove this result is to consider the composite morphism $R \to S \to S/J$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $\psi^{-1} (J)$ is an ideal, we know that $0 \in \psi^{-1} (J)$, so $\psi^{-1} (J)$ is not empty, and $ker \psi \subseteq \psi^{-1} (J)$ because $0 \in J$.

Now, let $a,b \in \psi^{-1} (J)$, so $\exists c,d \in J$ s.t $\psi (c) = a$ and $\psi (d) = b.$

So, $a-b = \psi (c) - \psi (d) = \psi (c-d)$.Since $c-d \in J$, $\psi (c-d) \in \psi^{-1}(J)$, hence $\psi^{-1} (J)$ is an abelian subgroups of $S$.

Similarly, $\psi (c*d) \in \psi^{-1} (J)$ and $\psi (d*c) \in \psi^{-1} (J)$, so $\psi^{-1} (J)$ is an ideal of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment, i made my own solution

Let $\psi^{-1} (J) = \{ r \in R | \psi(r) \in J\}$. Then clearly, $\psi^{-1}(\{0\}) = ker(\psi)$, $ker(\psi) \subset \psi^{-1}(J)$. Then next thing to show is $\psi^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal of $R$.

First, $(\psi^{-1}(J), +)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$. Since $\psi^{-1}(\{0\}) = 0_R \in \psi^{-1}(J)$, it is non-empty. So Let $a,b\in \psi^{-1}(J)$, then $\psi(a), \psi(b) \in J$, thus $\psi(a)-\psi(b) = \psi(a-b) \in \psi(J)$ gives $a-b\in \psi^{-1}(J)$.

Next thing to show that is for $r\in R$, then $ra \in \psi^{-1}(J)$ (left) and $ar \in \psi^{-1}(J)$ (right).

Since $\psi(ra) = \psi(r) \psi(a)$ and since $\psi(a) \in J$ and $J$ is ideal of $S$ (note $\psi(r) \in S$) thus $\psi(r) \psi(a) \in S J = J$, and similar way, $\psi(ar) = \psi(a) \psi(r) \in J R = J$.  Thus $\psi^{-1}(J)$ is a ideal of $R$ containing $ker(\psi)$.